# grabbing data and displaying it in block twig

Tags: 8, theming

bI made a custom module and made a custom block inside of it.

In the build () I have this.

```
return array (
  '#theme' => 'no_athlete_match_block',
  '#title' => 'Athletes With No Matching Name in the Database',
  '#description' => 'Displays the athletes with no matching name in the database for a given sporting event.',
);
```

In the .module file I have this.

```
function no_athlete_match_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'no_athlete_match_block' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'description' => NULL,
        'title' => NULL
      ),
      'template' => 'block--no_athlete_match',
    ),
  );
}
```

my twig file named block--no-athlete-match.html.twig

```
<div>
node: {{title}} {{description}}
```

Only Node: shows up. If I do dump(title) I get NULL to show up. Not sure what I'm missing. I've copied other blocks and still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So having playing around with it for two days I ended up commenting out template and listening to the twig debug recommendations. I then added the path so that I could have the template in my module folder. It might not be the best way to do this but it's working.

My module function

```
function no_athlete_match_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
return array(
 'no_athlete_match_block' => array(
          'variables' => array(
              'dsp' => NULL,
              'title' => NULL,
          ),
       //  'template' => 'no-athlete-match',
         'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'no_athlete_match') . '/templates'
      )
);
```

}

My block file

```
 return array (
            '#theme' => 'no_athlete_match_block',
            '#title' => 'Athletes With No Matching Name in the Database',
            '#description' => 'Displays the athletes with no matching name in the database for a given sporting event.',
            '#dsp' => $output,
        );
```

My Twig file.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Query</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>{{dsp.player}}</th>
            <th><small>{{dsp.notes}}</small></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've specified the `template` parameter in the [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x) function the template file name should be exactly as specified `block--no_athelete_match.html.twig`. The underscores are converted to dashes only in the case where the `template` parameter is not specified in the hook_theme function.

Comment: .tpl is for drupal 7. Do you mean .twig?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. I updated the file name.

Answer (score 0):

In your module file the suggestion of template will be only with underscores.

`block__no_athelete_match`

and in templates folder template name  needs to be only with dashes.

`block--no-athelete-match.html.twig`

Comment: That makes sense and I made the change but it still doesn't work after rebuilding cache.